# Python DEAP Multiprocessing example

Tags: python, multiprocessing, genetic-algorithm, deap

I am looking to speed up my DEAP code using multiprocessing. (sample code in [Unable to speed up Python DEAP with Multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61902235/unable-to-speed-up-python-deap-with-multiprocessing)

Does anybody has a simple code which successfully speed up DEAP using multiprocessing?

The only sample code which using multiprocessing in DEAP here https://github.com/DEAP/deap/blob/master/examples/ga/onemax_mp.py doesnt really speed up or use multi cores.

Comment: Even my code does not show any improvement by using multiprocessing, in fact, gets slower.